# Creating a pdf from byte type list in python

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to remove contact information from a pdf(that contains a MCQ question each page). I have extracted the text from the pdf and created a list containing the list of words that actually need. I am having trouble now creating a new pdf. Here is the code i used

```
'''from fpdf import FPDF '''
text = textract.process("/home/hari/Desktop/test.pdf")
#print(text)
words= []
words = text.split()
to_pop =[]
#print(words)
final = []
for i in range(len(words)):
  if(words[i]== b'Contact.' or words[i] == b':' or words[i] == b'8400-582-582,' or words[i] == b'8604-582-582' ):
    to_pop.append(i)
    words[i] = ''

for i in range(len(words)):
  if (i not in to_pop):
    final.append(words[i])
```

Now final contains all the text that is needed. How do I now create a new pdf from this?

A sample of the content contained in final is:

```
[b'egkeSjkF', b'ku', b'CHEMICAL', b'BONDING', b'with', b'Anurag', b'Sir', b'01', b'Out', b'of', b'following', b'which', b'one', b'has', b'least', b'value', b'of', b'melting', b'point', b'(A)', b'LiCl', b'(B)', b'BeCl2', b'(C)', b'MgCl2', b'(D)', b'CaCl2', b'02', b'Out', b'of', b'following', b'which', b'one', b'has', b'maximum', b'ionic', b'character', b'(A)', b'NaCl', b'(B)', b'KCl', b'(C)', b'CaCl2', b'(D)', b'MgCl2', b'03', b'Which', b'of', b'the', b'following', b'has', b'highest', b'melting', b'point', b'(A)', b'NaCl', b'(B)', b'NaI', b'(C)', b'NaBr', b'(D)', b'NaF', b'04', b'What', b'is', b'not', b'true', b'about', b'resonance', b'?', b'(A)', b'The', b'resonating', b'structures', b'are', b'hypothetical', b'(B)', b'The', b'unpaired', b'electrons', b'in', b'various', b'resonating', b'structures', b'are', b'same', b'(C)', b'Hybrid', b'structure', b'is', b'most', b'energetic', b'(D)', b'Hybrid', b'structure', b'is', b'least', b'energetic', b'05', b'Which', b'of', b'the', b'following', b'conditions', b'is', b'not', b'correct', b'for', b'resonating', b'structures', b'?', b'(A)', b'The', b'contributing', b'structures', b'must', b'have', b'the', b'same',
```

I need to create a new page for every question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have your list, `l`, of those bytes.
You can do the following:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
# multi_cell will wrap the input to it
pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, " ".join(i.decode('latin-1','replace') for i in l))

pdf.output('test_output.pdf')
```

Edit: FPDF uses latin-1 encoding by default so we have to decode into that.

Comment: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 753: ordinal not in range(256).

Getting that error. I tried pdf.output().encode('utf-8') . Did not work